# Ingress and Egress Rate of Solace Appliance

Tags: solace, solace-mq

I wanted to set Ingress and Egress Rate of Solace Appliance on below mentioned 3 level.

1 : Appliances Level
2 : Message-VPN Level
3 : Queue Level

Please let me know the possibility & share CLI Commend for same.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking if there is a way to set *rate limits* to ingress or egress traffic.

There is egress traffic shaping facility available on some NABs (e.g. NAB-0610EM, NAB-0210EM-04, NAB-0401ET-04, and NAB‑0801ET‑04) but it is per physical interface (port), e.g,

```
solace(configure/interface)# traffic-shaping
solace(configure/interface/traffic-shaping)# egress
solace(configure/interface/traffic-shaping/egress)# rate-limit <number-in-MBPS>
```

If your network RTT is significant enough, you might be able to do some "rate-limit" by constraining the TCP maximum send window size with a desired bandwidth-delay product. *Note that this is not a generic solution and will only work for certain cases, depending on the network environment.* It can be set on the client-profile for egress traffic:

```
solace(configure)# client-profile <name> message-vpn <vpn-name>
solace(configure/client-profile)# tcp max-wnd <num-kilo-bytes>
```

There is nothing you can do for rate-limiting ingress traffic on the appliance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe SolOS-TR supports rate limiting on the appliance side.

https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/Solace_Router_Feature_Provisioning/B_Managing_Consumption_of_Router_Resources.html